# salt.function не обрабатывает kwarg 'name'

Tags: python, linux, windows, saltstack

Имеется вот такой .sls файл:

```
service.restart:
  salt.function:
    - tgt: 'role:web'
    - tgt_type: grain
    - kwarg:
      name: 'svc_name'
```

Вот такой ответ:

```
      ID: service.restart
Function: salt.function
    Name: svc_name
  Result: False
 Comment: Running function svc_name failed on minions: srv_048_50 Function svc_name ran on srv_048_50.
 Started: 17:38:26.091795
Duration: 22341.386 ms
 Changes:
          srv_048_50:
              'svc_name' is not available.
```

Похоже, что kwarg 'name' перекрывает имя запускаемой функции, или я что-то делаю не так. Не подскажете, что именно?

Comment: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/25317#issuecomment-132582976

Comment: Отработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если конвертировать ваш файл в, например, `json`:

```
$ ruby -ryaml -rjson -e 'puts JSON.pretty_generate(YAML.load(ARGF))' test.yaml 
{
  "service.restart": {
    "salt.function": [
      {
        "tgt": "role:web"
      },
      {
        "tgt_type": "grain"
      },
      {
        "kwarg": null,
        "name": "svc_name"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

то можно увидеть, что `kwarg` и `name` «попадают» на один уровень в иерархии.

вам же требуется, вероятно, чтобы `name` находился на уровень глубже, т.е., был «подчинён» `kwarg`.

для этого либо добавьте ещё один отступ перед `name`:

```
- kwarg:
    name: ...
```

либо укажите подчинённость явно:

```
- kwarg: { name: ... }
```

Comment: Отработало, спасибо